# Xlib: Why am I having to close the display for mapping and unmapping windows?

Tags: x11, c

```c
// ...
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int rev;
  Window win;
  Display *dis = XOpenDisplay(NULL);

  XGetInputFocus(dis, &win, &rev);

  XUnmapWindow(dis, win);
  XCloseDisplay(dis);

  // ...

  dis = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
  XMapWindow(dis, win);
  XCloseDisplay(dis);

  return 0;
}
```

Note that before unmapping the window, I am having to close the display and as a result, I'm having to reinitialize it before mapping to have the program working properly.
What's going on here?

#### Solution:

```c
// ...
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int rev;
  Window win;
  Display *dis = XOpenDisplay(NULL);

  XGetInputFocus(dis, &win, &rev);

  XUnmapWindow(dis, win);
  XFlush(dis); // The fix

  //...

  XMapWindow(dis, win);
  XCloseDisplay(dis);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't have to do this. Who says you need to? E.g. the window manager maps and unmaps windows all the time, without closing the display connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need call XCloseDisplay after XUnmapWindow. If that does not work, you must have some other error in your program that might mess up some variable?

Here is an example I have tried quickly. It unmaps and maps a window and it does not require XCloseDisplay/XOpenDisplay in between.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
 
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Display *display;
    Window window;
    XSetWindowAttributes attributes;
    XGCValues gr_values;
    XFontStruct *fontinfo;
    GC gr_context;
    Visual *visual;
    int depth;
    int screen;
    XEvent event;
    XColor color, dummy;

    display = XOpenDisplay (NULL);
    screen = DefaultScreen (display);
    visual = DefaultVisual (display,screen);
    depth  = DefaultDepth (display,screen);
    attributes.background_pixel = XWhitePixel (display,screen);
 
    window = XCreateWindow (display, XRootWindow (display, screen), 200, 200, 350, 200, 5, depth, InputOutput, visual, CWBackPixel, &attributes);
    XSelectInput (display, window, ExposureMask | KeyPressMask) ;
    fontinfo = XLoadQueryFont (display, "6x10");

    XAllocNamedColor (display, DefaultColormap (display, screen), "red", &color, &dummy);
 
    gr_values.font = fontinfo->fid;
    gr_values.foreground = color.pixel;
    gr_context = XCreateGC (display, window, GCFont + GCForeground, &gr_values);
    XFlush (display);
    XMapWindow (display, window);
    XFlush (display);

    int keypressed = 0;
    while (!keypressed) {
        XNextEvent (display, &event);

        switch (event.type) {
            case Expose:
                XDrawLine (display, window, gr_context, 0, 0, 100, 100);
                XDrawString (display, window, gr_context, 100, 100, "hello1", 6);
                break;
            case KeyPress: 
                keypressed = 1;
                XUnmapWindow (display, window);
                XFlush (display);
                break;
        }
    }

    sleep (1);
    XMapWindow (display, window);
    XFlush (display);

    while (1) {
        XNextEvent (display, &event);

        switch (event.type) {
            case Expose:
                XDrawLine (display, window, gr_context, 50, 50, 100, 100);
                XDrawString (display, window, gr_context, 50, 50, "hello2", 6);
                break;
            case KeyPress: 
                XCloseDisplay (display); 
                exit (0);
        }
    }
}
```

The program waits until you press a key. It then unmaps and maps again. On next keypress it exits. Compile it with

```
gcc -o programname programname.c -lX11
```

Sample is taken from here: http://www-h.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/tpl/graphics/X/X11R5/node21.html

Comment: Okay, I just had to flush the display after unmapping instead of closing it.
Thanks for the help. =)